# Как определить нагрузку на сервер или MySQL с помощью PHP либо PERL?

Tags: python, highload, perl, php, mysql

Есть высоко нагруженный сайт, просто аффигенно нагруженный

И есть довольно слабенький для него сервер

Задача проста:

Нужно как то перед запуском основного функционального кода проверять на сколько загружен сервер и MySQL

(В первую очередь лучше проверять MySQL)

Результат допустим в процентах выводить или еще как

Вот как такое можно сделать на PHP либо PERL, но желательней ПХП?

Логика проста, если допустим сервер загружен на 85% то выбрасываем статику

На сервере установлен модуль python, я не шарю особо в нем, но если есть что по теме на нем и можно запустить то пишите

Comment: Для начала, какая ОС?

--

Вообще задача значительно сложнее, чем кажется на первый взгляд. И дело не в том, вывод какой утилиты парсить (IMHO если брать одну, то  в \*nix vmstat лучшая из них),  а в понимании **что такое загруженность сервера**.

Возможно, позже вернусь к обсуждению этого вопроса.

Comment: CentosOS

Загруженность это когда база данных вылетает и таблицы рушатся
вот мне нужно это избежать

База пишется сообщение - Много конеектов и отрубается
В итоге таблицы портятся

Comment: @dgfhgjljhjjd, в этом случае измерения процентов CPU и памяти (и т.п.) Вам не помогут. 

Надо отслеживать соединения с сервером СУБД. Не знаю, в Вашем случае это сокеты, FIFO или сегменты разделяемой памяти (надо где-то в руководствах  искать). Вот эти ресурсы и надо отслеживать. Возможно стоит посмотреть на файлы в /proc для MySQL сервера (почитайте man 5 proc).

А вообще, таблицы портятся - это странно. При нормальной организации транзакций такого не должно происходить даже при выключении питания.

Answer (score 2):

А почему собственно писать тесты производительность на php? Простой бенчмарк можно сварганить буквально за минуту прямо в окошке терминала, написав простой скрипт для bash:

```
while :; do ps waux | grep mysql| grep -v grep >>  mysql_benchmark.log; sleep 3; done
```

Здесь пускается бесконечный цикл, который вызывает команду `ps` с опциями, `grep`-ом отфильтровываем нужный процесс из списка и перенаправляем результат в файл. Не трудно догадаться, что `ps` запскается каждые 3 секунды, пока ты не нажмёшь CTRL+C.

После запуска вышеописанной команды даёшь на сервер нагрузку(ручками или другим скриптом). После окончания работы прерываешь работу скрипта.

Пришла пора анализировать полученный лог-файл. Самыми интересными столбцами для нас являются третий(%CPU - сколько процентов от процессора потреблял mysql ), пятый(VSZ - сколько виртуальной памяти забрал себе наш подопытный) и шестой(RSS - сколько реальных страниц памяти кушал процесс). Описание всех столбцов нужно смотреть в `man ps`.

```
$ cat mysql_benchmark.log | awk '{print $3, $5, $6}'
0.0 1979852 32376
0.0 1979852 32376
0.0 1979852 32376
и ещё много циферок...
```

После фильтра CPU стал первым, VSZ - вторым, а RSS - третьим столбцом. У меня, как видишь, mysql процесс спит и памяти ест немного. На большие размеры VSZ зачастую можно забить на 64-битных боксах, так как адресное пространство у каждого процесса своё и оно виртуальное.

Главное, смотреть на CPU и RSS. Если CPU близок к 100% в течении теста, не помешает докупить процессор помощнее, если RSS mysql большой и близок к суммарному объёму памяти на машине, скоро система начнёт заталкивать ненужные процессы в своп, а потом убивать самые жирные процессы. При этом mysql - первый кандидат на убиение, по странному умолчанию. Решается это зачатую покупкой планки памяти.

Если mysql использует слишком мало памяти, и работает медленно, то скорее всего, тебе нужно подкрутить ряд настроек в mysql.conf для используемых storange engines. Вот [этот доклад](http://vimeo.com/42612197) может быть полезным в этом вопросе.

Ещё не мешает померить объём ввода-вывода на жестком диске и сетевом интерфейсе, но это уже не так просто, и это совсем другая история. Косвенный народный признак: если наблюдаются тормоза - скорее всего, идёт активный ввод-вывод, и скорее всего на жёсткий диск. Для нормальной работы всего приложения нужно, чтобы объём "*горячих*" данных не превышал объём памяти, выделенной для mysql.

Ещё добавлю, что перед проведением теста желательно дать всей системы "*разогреться*" несколько минут - поюзать просто свою приложение без замеров, чтобы все успели подчитать самые часто используемые данные с диска в ОЗУ.

Похожую простую методику не раз применял для простых бенчмарков различных приложений: mysql, apache, серверные Python-процессы . Работает даже в Windows:) Но там используются батники и немного другие утилиты.

Comment: красивый ответ, спасибо

Comment: @dred, ответ хороший, но похоже у автора проблема в другом: 

    База пишется сообщение - Много конеектов и отрубается В итоге таблицы портятся

это он в одном из комментариев написал.

Comment: Ну я как общую методику написал, как ответ на изначальный вопрос. Сейчас как раз углубляюсь в бенчмарки mysql на работе, вот и не удержался.

Answer (score 1):

**ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ**

В общем выполняю вот такие вот запросы

```
system('cat /proc/cpuinfo');

system('cat /proc/meminfo');

system('free');

$load = sys_getloadavg();
foreach($load as $k => $v) {
echo $k.' ---> '.$v;
}
```

**и получаю результат**

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5345  @ 2.33GHz
stepping    : 7
cpu MHz     : 2327.558
cache size  : 4096 KB
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 apic sep cmov pat clflush acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht nx constant_tsc up pni ssse3
bogomips    : 4663.96
clflush size    : 64

power management:

MemTotal:       786628 kB
MemFree:          9972 kB
Buffers:         14276 kB
Cached:         639356 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:         617804 kB
Inactive:       117144 kB
HighTotal:       44800 kB
HighFree:          180 kB
LowTotal:       741828 kB
LowFree:          9792 kB
SwapTotal:           0 kB
SwapFree:            0 kB
Dirty:           24336 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:       81320 kB
Mapped:          16844 kB
Slab:            18412 kB
SReclaimable:    12924 kB
SUnreclaim:       5488 kB
PageTables:          0 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
WritebackTmp:        0 kB
CommitLimit:    393312 kB
Committed_AS:   402556 kB
VmallocTotal:   114680 kB
VmallocUsed:      3040 kB
VmallocChunk:   111272 kB

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        786628     775976      10652          0      14292     639400
-/+ buffers/cache:     122284     664344
Swap:            0          0          0

0 ---> 9.47
1 ---> 7.96
2 ---> 5.68
```

Как то можно этим воспользоваться?

Comment: Полюбоваться можно, понять, что у тебя за система. А вот про mysql ничего скзать нельзя. Для анализа общей загрузки системы у тебя есть 3 реальных цифры, как их анализировать, можно на wiki почитать: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing). Например, 5.68 значит что в течении последних 15 минут была загружена на 468% относительно средней загрузки(т.е. 4.68 процесса в среднем ждали, не могли дождаться твоего процессора)

Answer (score 0):

Есть [`mtop`](http://mtop.sourceforge.net/), можно попробовать парсить его вывод, для определения загрузки MySQL.

Или парсить ответ обычного топа.

```
[root@swift ~]$ top -b -n 1 -u mysql
top - 08:57:15 up 33 days, 22:35,  2 users,  load average: 0.21, 0.31, 0.20
Tasks: 110 total,   1 running, 109 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 14.4% us,  1.0% sy,  0.0% ni, 83.7% id,  0.3% wa,  0.1% hi,  0.6% si
Mem:   6106276k total,  3953372k used,  2152904k free,   376748k buffers
Swap:  4192956k total,      124k used,  4192832k free,  1574960k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
4046 mysql     16   0  170m  42m 5092 S  0.0  0.7   1300:11 mysqld
```

ну все в кроне и все такое..

Comment: @Anton Shevtsov, и на как по Вашему надо интерпретировать эти данные для вычисления порога загрузки, которым интересуется автор?

Comment: эмпирическим путём, как же еще)) %CPU + %MEM + load average + сферический конь в вакууме

Comment: Вот в коне-то (вообще, коэффициенте при нем (да еще и неконстантном)) вся проблема.

Answer (score 0):

для скли можно использовать

```
show processlist;
show status;
```

Comment: да но как из ПХП выполнить эти запросы?

там же нужно авторизоваться и потом только их выполнить

с помощью того что я написал выше не катит

Comment: `mysql_query` же... если какая то проблема, то запрос вам вернет ошибку, которую вы и проанализируете...

Comment: хотя лучше задуматься об обновлении либо хотябы про load-balancing